# Динамический массив JAVA

Tags: java

В C++ динамический массив в классе описывался так:

```
class YepYep{
private: int **array;
public: YepYep{
array = new int*[50];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    array [i] = new int[50];};
```

Как по тому же принципу выделить массив в Java для класса, который будет использоваться в методах класса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Фиксированный:

```
public class Jaba {

    private int[][] x;

    public Jaba() {
        x = new int[50][50]; // никто не мешает объявить и без конструктора
    }
}
```

Динамический и немного больший, чем просто массив

```
public class Jaba {

    private List<Integer> x = new ArrayList();

}
```

Comment: Все равно не понимаю, необходимо инициализировать двумерный массив под класс и в конструкторе выделить под него память. Прочитал про List и про Vector. Про Vector пишут что его надо использовать только когда многопоточность, так как работа занимает с ним времени и памяти, а с ArrayList/List не могу разобраться

Comment: @ParanoidPanda джава сама выделяет и возвращает память. Вектор - устаревшее, и, действительно, синхронизированное барахло, которое не нужно использовать, достаточно обернуть существующий экземпляр в `Collections.synchronizedList()`. List - это просто список произвольных объектов, который берет на себя работу по расширению нижележащего массива (или того, что использует имплементация).

Answer (score 0):

возможно это подойдет?

создание

```
 public String[][] readingDataCsv = new String[1000][1000];
```

заполнение

```
 readingDataCsv[i][0] = parts[0];
```

чтение

```
 //выбор строки номер3 и столбца номер2
  System.out.println("---readingParts--"+readingDataCsv[0][0]+"|"+readingDataCsv[0][1]+"--------");
```